# mongoose connection as a separate module in nodejs app

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

In my project I want to make a separate module to get mongoose connection,say connection.js ,

```
        var mongoose = require('mongoose');
        mongoose.connect('mongodb://host:port/db');
        mongoose.connection.on('connected', function () {
            console.log('Mongoose default connection open to localhost:27017' );


        // If the connection throws an error
        mongoose.connection.on('error',function (err) {

            console.log('Mongoose default connection error: ' + err);

        });

        // When the connection is disconnected
        mongoose.connection.on('disconnected', function () {
            console.log('Mongoose default connection disconnected'); 

        });
        module.exports= mongoose;
```

which I can import using require in another file,say file1.js , as

```
    var connect_to_mongoose = require('connection');
```

whenever necessary.
But I have came across the problem that since in nodejs IO is async then how can i make sure that the connection is successful and I can now use connect_to_mongoose variable for queries,insertions,deletions etc.

My second question is that after handling the above scenario how can I manage multiple connections for multiple databases. Bcoz as far as i know(for practical reasons) in mongoose one connection is dedicated to one DB only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should consider scenarios while working with mongodb and mongoose.

1. mongoose.connect opens a default connection as soon as app starts
2. you don't have to create every time a new connection if you are dealing with multiple tables / collections (whatever you call).
3. if you are dealing with multiple databases then you've separate your mongodb url like **mongoose.connect(mongodb://localhost/db1) && mongoose.connect(mongodb://localhost/db2)**
4. But above point no. 3 would give you an **Warning : Trying to Close an open connection**
5. To solve above issue just use the following :

   var db = mongoose.createConnection(mongodb://localhost/db1)

And after your all tasks are completed **close the connection**

Cheers :)